# Unable to provide href or onclick event on div

Tags: html

I have a following code in my HTML where I am trying to load images and they shd get changed as per the screen resolution so I kept their position as relative. My problem is how to provide onclick or href on my.png image. 
Please suggest.

```
<div id="main">
      <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; " id="header" >
        <img src="images/logo.png"  width="100%" height="100"
              style="position: relative; z-index:10;"/>
        <div style="position: relative; top:-80px;left:72%;">
              <img src="images/my.png"  width="5%" height="70"  style=""/>
        </div>
        <div  style="position: relative; top:-150px;left:79%;">
            <a href="" >
                <img  src="images/connect.png" width="5%" height="70"
                    usemap="#button_connect"/> 
            </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include some HTML and CSS code or a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) in your post so we have something to go on. Edit: nevermind he just posted it.

Comment: @villeman Actually, I edited the question to include some source code formating, the the HTML is not affected by the tag stripping on stackoverflow.

Comment: @user2849371 Please proofread the question after you posted it, especially because as a new user you are not yet familiar with the input format.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the image with HTML `anchor`

```
<div style="position: relative; top:-80px;left:72%;">
    <a href="your-url">
        <img src="images/my.png"  width="5%" height="70"  style=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried applying "#" and even providing a url to my <a href> but i still seem to have no response of my url when i place my cursor on top of the image.
Any other suggestions

Comment: What url did you provide?